# how to Convert CSV file to GZIP file with use of multiprocessing. Pool in Python

Tags: python-3.x, csv, multiprocessing, gzip

I am using gzip to convert csv file into gunzip file.I am trying to implement multiprocessing to make the process faster. But when i run my code it doesn't even give me the output, it keeps on running and doesn't give error either. Below is my code

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import gzip
path= r'D:\All Files'
def convertToGzip(file):
    file_ = os.path.join(path, file)
    print('File {} is being Converted'.format(file_))
    with open(os.path.join(path, file_), 'rb') as f_in:
        with gzip.open(file+'.gz', 'wb') as f_out:
            shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
            
a_pool = Pool(processes=4)
result = a_pool.map(convertToGzip, os.listdir(path))
```

I donot understand where is the issue here , since I do not know much about Multiprocessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import gzip
import os
import shutil

from multiprocessing import Pool

PATH = "D:\All Files"


def convert_to_gzip(fname):
    fpath = os.path.join(PATH, fname)

    print("File {} is being Converted".format(fpath))

    with open(fpath, "rb") as f_in:
        with gzip.open(fpath + ".gz", "wb") as f_out:
            shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)


def main():
    with Pool() as pool:
        result = pool.map(convert_to_gzip, os.listdir(PATH))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```